# 401 (Unauthorized) When calling Sharepoint Query

Tags: javascript, iis, sharepoint, cors

I am currently getting this error 401 when I try to call my Sharepoint Endpoint. It occurred after I added the following below into the header. What is the issue here? I am unsure if this is an issue with IIS or the Sharepoint Configurations, please advice. Thank you!

My Response:
**GET http://www.test.com/Shared%20Documents/query%20result%20BEFORE.xml 401 (Unauthorized)**

Previously, I was facing this error:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at **** from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:1234' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I added the **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** with a value of "*" in the HTTP Response Headers and now I am getting the 401 error.

My code:

```
  function testCall2() {
        const xhr1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
        const URL= "http://test.com/_api/search/query?querytext=%27BEFORE%27"

        xhr1.open("GET", URL);
        xhr1.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhr1.readyState === 4) {
                if (xhr1.status === 200) {
                    const response = xhr1.responseText;
                    // Process the response as needed
                    console.log(`XHR1 Success!! ${response}`);
                } else {
                    console.error('XHR1 Error:', xhr1.statusText);
                }
            }
        };
        xhr1.send();
    }
```

Comment: Please post the details about the 401 error, or you can also use the failed request trace to view the detailed error information.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource—when trying to get data from a REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871637/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-whe)

Answer (score 1):

You need to send authorization, if your code runs at localhost (is not a part of the sharepoint page). Now you do not send any. 401 is not "access denied", it is "authorization required".

The above code would be legal and work, if it was running as a part of SharePoint page (the cookie authorization will be used automatically). But if the code comes from a third-party server, you need to authorize explcitly.